# Package XIB in Swift framework for distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xib

I'm creating a Swift framework so I can distribute it via CocoaPods and Carthage. My question is if it is possible to distribute a .xib files in my framework? If so, how would the consuming developer use it?

Comment: I think you can put your xib in a resource bundle and then use `NSBundle` to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your .xib file from your framework like this :

```
UINib(nibName: "MyXib", bundle: NSBundle(identifier: "bundleName")
```

or if you know the name of a class in the framework

```
UINib(nibName: "MyXib", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)
```